Representations of $G$ and $S_n$ on $V^{\otimes n}$
I am reading through notes learning a first course in representation theory, and I can't figure out how something stated in lectures follows:
Let $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ be an $d$-dimensional representation over $\mathbb{C}$ of a finite group $G$. $V^{\otimes n}$ can be made into a representation of G via $g \cdot (v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_n) = (\rho(g)v_1) \otimes \ldots \otimes (\rho(g)v_n)$. It can also be made into a representation of $S_n$, via $\sigma \cdot (v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_n) = v_{\sigma^{-1}(1)} \otimes \ldots \otimes v_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}$.
These two actions should commute. I think I can show this, since one action is just permuting prodands and the other is uniformly applying some $g$ to all prodands at the same time, so it wouldn't matter which happened first. The lecturer then says that it follows from this that:

since the two actions commute, we can decompose $V^{\otimes n}$ as an $S_n$-module, and each isotypical component is a G-invariant subspace of $V^{\otimes n}$

(with the notes then moving on to something else). I've had a look at lecture notes from several other similar representation theory courses (and in some books) but any time this is mentioned the result is asserted to follow from the actions commuting. I'm not really seeing how to use that though.
I've tried looking at what the isotypical components of the $S_n$-module would be, and my best guess is that it's spaces generated by tensor products of basis vectors where the quantities of each basis vector occurring are fixed. I'm thinking this probably is more than is needed and there should be a simpler way of seeing this fact (or of course I could be misunderstanding what is claimed).

Suppose $V$ is simultaneously a $G$-rep and an $H$-rep, and that the two actions commute (this is equivalent to being a $(G\times H)$-rep, but we don't need that). If $U\le V$ is an $H$-subrep of $V$, then there is an isomorphism $U\cong g U$ of $H$-reps given by $u\mapsto gu$. Thus, $G$ permutes the $H$-subirreps of $V$ of a given type (isomorphism class). Since an isotypical component of $V$ (as an $H$-rep) is the sum of all $H$-subirreps of a given type, it is stable under the application of $g$, i.e. a $G$-subrep.
If you know the isotypical component is the image of the isotypical projector (an element of the group algebra), and you know this projector commutes with the action of the other group, you can show the isotypical component is stable that way too.

Ah thank you, I realise now I had wrongly conflated "isotypical component" with "irreducible subrepresentation", this now makes sense to me
